# Surface analysis of / construction from 3D point set

Tags: 3d, computational-geometry, geometry-surface

I am aware there are a number of answered posts on this topic in general and I did my share of reading these, but chances are I missed some or misunderstood others, so sorry in advance if this has already been explained elsewhere.

**What I have**
A set of 3D points like this:

[image]

Or for better visibility with Delaunay tetrahedralized surface with wire mesh: [image]

These points describe the surface I'm interested in.

**What I want**

Ultimately, I would like to have a closed surface that contains every point, while minimizing connectivity between points. (The goal is then to compute an estimate of the area per point by doing some sort of Voronoi-like compartmentalization of the facets: halving the connections between points and allocating facet segments that are delimited by the normals starting from the so introduced halving-points to the closest points.)

The part in parenthesis I would have to figure out if I ever get to the surface I'm aiming at. I just added this because it may further clarify what I intend to construct.

I should add that I have rather basic knowledge of geometry. During a different project I stumbled upon the concepts of the convex hull and alpha shapes but I figured neither would be of much use in this case. Maybe all I would need is a pointer to the right keyword.. I already got convinced that surface reconstruction from point data is far more complicated than I initially anticipated, so although it sounds solvable to me I guess there's a chance it's not.

Anayways, thanks for your help!

Edit: spelling

Comment: Despite your explanations, I have no idea what you are after. "minimizing connectivity" ???

Comment: Ok sorry let me rephrase: I mean a closed surface that is constructed from the lowest possible number of edges extending from each point. I wrote this because I experimented with the alpha-value used for surface generation in e.g. ParaView and noticed that with the right value all points cosntitute vertices but edges and facets are introduced that sort of "float" (if that makes sense). On the other hand, the so generated surface isn't closed anymore, so maybe this minimum number of edges is already inherent to a closed surface (sorry like I said, I lack knowledge in this regard).

Comment: You can link all points in a loop and wrap this in a surface. Connectivity = 2. I guess that your problem is ill-posed.

Comment: If I understand your suggestion correctly, then yes, this would lead to minimum connectivity. But it would not yield a closed surface since the facets would not be well defined. You are right, it may still be ill-posed, and this got me thinking: let me remove this criterion and say I want to generate a triangular mesh where my points are vertices. This should work equally well for my purposes. I will update the question if you confirm the question is now more clearly treatable.

Comment: do you mean that all points must be vertices of the mesh ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, yes that is exactly what I mean!

Comment: Tetrahedrize the points and remove faces to make the network a manifold.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Any method that comes to mind that I can look into? Ad hoc, I feel a sophisticated procedure is needed to find the relevant tetrahedra or am I overthinking and it is actually straight forward?

Comment: Delaunay tetrahedization.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I did in picture no. 2. It contains all points as vertices, but not necessarily at the surface (you can see in the picture that some are inside. One could probably remove specific faces to ultimately expose all points but the question is what algorithm to use in this selection process.(?)

Comment: If you can implement a "manifoldness" test, then a greedy approach should work.

Comment: Ok, I did some reading, I'm not a mathematician and these concepts are new to me. I finally came across some interesting articles on surface reconstruction from 3D scans, with which I identify my problem in so far as these scans lead to the knowledge of vertices but not of edges and faces. Apparently this is far from something that is easily implemented and requires sophisticated methods such as Ball Pivoting algorithm or Poisson reconstruction.

Comment: Funny to see that you ruled out Alpha shapes and are now coming back to them.

Comment: I once again point out that I am new to this subject and am severely lacking background knowledge. I did not make the connection between Alpha shapes and these methods. Probably because the literature I used covers the topic in an oversimplified fashion. I ruled out Alpha shapes because in my understanding this would require a qualitative re-verification of the generated surface if the vertices were arranged in a different manner (variation in spacing) and would severely hamper quantitative analysis of large amounts of sets.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you don't want a surface that contains every point. Such a surface is most likely highly unstable w.r.t. point changes and the Voronoi areas you get will be somewhat random. Can't you do Voronoi volumes instead? Btw, if you have a triangle mesh of a sphere-like object, the number of faces and edges is already determined by the number of vertices as `f = 2 v - 4` and `e = 3 v - 6`. The problem looks similar to finding a Hamiltonian circle in a graph - just for surfaces.